# Regex: Escaped pattern in Eclipse, doesn't matches the same words as before

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, escaping

I'm working on a KATA at [codewars.com](http://www.codewars.com) and have the task to replace any occurence of `you`, `u` and `youuu` (not limited number of u) in a string with `your sister`.

I have working code and figured out following Regex-expression for the case `youuuu`

> (you*[\s\W])

Now in eclipse, I need to escape the "\", so the expression is like:

> (you*[\\s\\W])

However, this doesn't match the same words as the expression before.

**Here's my code:**

```
public static String autocorrect(String input) {
    String[] splittedInput = input.split(" ");
    StringBuilder formattedString = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : splittedInput){
        switch (word) {
        case "u":
            formattedString.append("your sister");
            break;
        case "you":
            formattedString.append("your sister");
            break;
        default:
            if (word.matches("(you*[\\s\\W])")){
                formattedString.append("your sister");
            }
            else {
             formattedString.append(word);   
            }
        }
        formattedString.append(" ");
    }

    return formattedString.toString();
}
```

It doesn't match words like `youuuuuuu` anymore, or `youu`  or `youu`...
Why doesn't it work in Eclipse if it works in an online-Regex-Tester?

Comment: Why do you need to escape the backslash ?

Comment: @Esteban: Because in java string literals, the backslashes need to be escaped; otherwise, they signal the start of a special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `(you*[\\s\\W])` matches strings containing `yo`, followed by an arbitrary number of `u` (may be zero as well), followed by a **mandatory** whitespace or non-word character.

You probably want the change it to something like this:

```
(you+[\\s\\W]?)
```

However your initial expression should match `youu!` already contrary to your description.

Additionally you may want to use a `Matcher` as well to match subsequences in a string against your pattern as mentioned in one of the other answers:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(you+[\\s\\W]?)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("youuuuuu!");
matcher.find();
```

Comment: If you're using `Matcher::matches`, you might as well drop the `[\\s\\W]?` -- meaning this will also match `"youufoobar"`, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Actually, I see `matches()` does not in fact match substrings (`find()` does)

Answer (score 1):

In Java when you use `matches()` it automatically appends to the regex `$` in the front and `^` to the end, acting like you want to match the whole word. You can use a `Matcher` and `Pattern` to get around this better.

Comment: They're already splitting on space first, so *if* all words are delimited by spaces in the input, this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern includes a whitespace or non-word character at the end. Without such a character, it won't match. Also note that you split on " " at the beginning, so passing "youu " to `autocorrect` will match the pattern against "youu" after splitting, which won't match because there's no whitespace at the end anymore.

Other than that, it seems your function does what it's supposed to, except that it seems you need to use a `+` instead of an `*` to match at least one `u` to conform to your stated problem.

Comment: wasn't aware that '*' means the specified char can also be not-present, thx!